# Why does my Crucial M4-CT128 SSD only achieve about 30 MB/s on writes?

Tags: performance, ssd

What can be the reason of limited to 30MB/s write speed to Crucial M4-CT128 SSD drive on Windows 10.
Disk was before in different laptop with Win7 achieving higher write speeds.
I noticed that after firmware upgrade, next test achieved higher speeds, but after system restart (I believe) write speeds came back to ~30MB/s

- TRIM support enabled
- interface SATA III
- enabled AHCI
- latest SSD Firmware
- enabled write caching on the device
- enough free space for test (about 99GB)
- partition aligned

Benchmark: ATTO

[image]

Benchmark: AS SSD

[image]

Comment: You don't mention if you are connecting the drive to a SATA III port or not.  Windows 10 automatically enables TRIM when it detects a SSD, so I very much doubt, it has anything to do with TRIM not being enabled.  In reality the drive is in general [slow](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Crucial-M4-128GB/Rating/1929) compared to other SSDs on the market.  You are actually getting very close to the average write speed of that device.  What tool did you use to benchmark this drive?

Comment: also post a picture of AS SSD Benchmark: http://alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?cat_id=4&download_id=9

Comment: @Ramhound: please see completed details.

Comment: @magicandre1981: included test from AS SSD, didn't have patience to wait for test to run completely

Comment: is this the latest firmware for the M4 SSD?

Comment: @magicandre1981: yes 070H

Comment: ok, try the suggestion of the answer and try to trigger a full TRIM. Alos try to run the Defrag UI and optimize the SSD: **"C:\Windows\system32\dfrgui.exe"**

Answer (score 0):

You have to TRIM your drive, which evidently is in a full-used state ([here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4253/the-crucial-m4-micron-c400-ssd-review/2) you can find some related benchmark)

You can use [trimcheck](https://github.com/CyberShadow/trimcheck) to be sure that TRIM is enabled, and follow [these suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/479239/win7-how-do-i-force-trim-on-ssd-when-system-partition-is-encrypted-with-truecr) to trigger a full freespace TRIM.

Comment: Yes TRIM is supported/enabled.

Comment: Just to try I used app mentioned here http://superuser.com/questions/203956/how-to-manually-trim-an-ssd-in-windows-7 to force TRIM, it didn't help.